# Taking long time to load index page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC project, there are more than 4000 records to be shown on the Index page.

Because the records numbers are high, loading time has gone to more than 4-5 minutes.

Is there any simple way to show all the data in less time?

This is my controller code.

```
 public ActionResult Index() {

   List < MyRequestViewModel > myRequests = new List < MyRequestViewModel > ();
   var req = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "UserId").FirstOrDefault();
   int EmpId = int.Parse(req.Value);

   if (Lvl != 1) {

     var MyRequests = (from a in db.AppRequest join Rtype in db.Request_Types on a.ReqType equals Rtype.Id join ApState in db.M_ApprovalStatus on a.Approval_Status equals ApState.Id where a.Create_By == EmpId select new MyReq {
       ReqNumber = a.Id,
         ReqType = Rtype.Request_Type,
         CreatedDate = a.Created_Date,
         ReqHeading = a.Req_Heading,
         ReqTimeline = ApState.Approval_Status_Name
     }).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ReqNumber);

     return View(MyRequests);
   } else {
     var MyRequests = (from a in db.AppRequest join Rtype in db.Request_Types on a.ReqType equals Rtype.Id join ApState in db.M_ApprovalStatus on a.Approval_Status equals ApState.Id where a.Status == true select new MyReq {
       ReqNumber = a.Id,
         ReqType = Rtype.Request_Type,
         CreatedDate = a.Created_Date,
         ReqHeading = a.Req_Heading,
         ReqTimeline = ApState.Approval_Status_Name
     }).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ReqNumber);

     TempData["IfsReff"] = TempData["mydata"];
     return View(MyRequests);
   }

 }
```

This is the View

```
@model IEnumerable<Asp_PASMVC.ViewModels.MyReq>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="MyRequest" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 1%"> Request Number </th>
          <th> Request Type </th>
          <th> Created Date </th>
          <th> Request Heading </th>
          <th> Request Timeline </th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody> @foreach (var item in Model) { var editClass = item.ReqTimeline == "Department Head" ? "" : "btn-primary disabled"; var ApproveClass = item.ReqTimeline == "Approved" ? "" : "btn-success disabled"; <tr>
          <td> @item.ReqNumber </td>
          <td> @item.ReqType </td>
          <td> @item.CreatedDate </td>
          <td> @item.ReqHeading </td>
          <td> @item.ReqTimeline </td>
          <td> @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary pull-right "+editClass })*@ <div class="btn-group"> @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ReqNumber }, new { @target = "_blank", @class = "btn btn-warning pull-right" }) <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat dropdown-toggle dropdown-icon" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="ViewCanceledReason(@item.ReqNumber)">View canceled reason</button>
              </div>
            </div> @Html.ActionLink("Download Approval", "Download_PDF", "ReportsViewModel", new { id = item.ReqNumber }, new { @target = "_blank", @class = "btn btn-success pull-right" + ApproveClass }) <button onclick="confirmDelete(@item.ReqNumber);" , class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Cancel</button>
          </td>
        </tr> } </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

I'm using a bootstrap pagination table

Comment: IMHO Don't. A user can only see so much data on the screen at once. So only load one "page" of data at a time. Note that you can detect scrolling in javascript to auto load more pages as the user scrolls, to give the illusion that they already have all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of loading data using razor you can load data using json and set data to view through JavaScript then You will get the performance very high. Go to this link to see how you can show data.

```
https://abctutorial.com/post/227/get-user-list-using-aspnet-mvc--jquery--ajax
```

Comment: @RexaKarim Thank you for the answer. Also Is there any way of binding the results with the Bootstrap table I'm using here? 'cus pagination and search options are not working for the above code when I applied to mine.